# Not using eloquent . How using providers auth with driver = database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

Laravel supported driver  "**database**" or "**eloquent**" to authorize website .
In default **config/auth.php**  we can see it alway declare drive is eloquent.

````
    ``` 
       /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | User Providers
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
        | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
        | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
        |
        | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
        | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
        | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
        |
        | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
        |
        */
    
        'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Models\Users::class,
            ],
    
            // 'users' => [
            //     'driver' => 'database',
            //     'table' => 'users',
            // ],
        ],
    ```
````

Then we have a mode **User** refer with table User to check authentication.
So we can using some method of **auth** : **auth::check(),auth::atemp(),auth:login(),...**
If I dont using Model App\Models\Users::class,. I using **'driver' => 'database'**. How i can auhorize by using some function of **auth** ,

Comment: then you would have to use `database` driver and declare the table in the configuration

Comment: i want to use  dirver database  because i have multi DB .  I think  it difficult to auth that  understand  table  which declared  Belong DB A or DB B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the drive to database, you can easily comment out the eloquent part and uncomment the driver database section, you can use auth() normally as you were using before. Laravel's auth works out of the box.

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'users', //Or whatever table you are using for users.
]
```

You can design your signIn method in your AuthController, like bellow:

```
public function signIn(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return redirect('login')->withErrors('Login details are invalid');
    }
```

It will work in both eloquent and database drivers.

Comment: Thanks you. but if I use many databases, how can auth understand the table that I declare to use for which database?.   Example :   In .Env  I have connect to DB A  and when login i will  conect to DB A to get infor  DB B, then  I connect to  DB B have table **user**  . How auth can't understand that table user locate in DB B.

Comment: Can I see your .env and config/database.php?

Comment: in ENV
```DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DB_A
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123
```
  in file config/database.php:
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),

Comment: when login . i will get infor DB_B (host,database,URL, username , pasword,...) from table DBtaget from databse  DB_A .  so i  conect  to DB_B by function mysqli_connect from PHP

Comment: Well, while working with multiple databases, there are many factors to be considered and it is hard to explain them in the comment box. In you .env I don't even see a second database connection? Please visit this link that is a detailed explaination of how to work with multiple databases in laravel: https://codelapan.com/post/how-to-use-multiple-database-connections-in-laravel-8

Comment: tks  you so muck . . I think i figure out solution